# Which is the better chip, the Opteron 270, or the Opteron 1212?

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, opteron

I tried looking at the specs but they seem very similar, and I'm not sure which is the more powerful or feature rich chip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalability is the main difference. The 270 can scale to 2 way while the 1212 can go to 1. the leading digit determines the scalability. That seems to me to be the main difference from what I can see. This is given if you were looking at the two models with similar clocks and cache.
[Made a little comparison chart for you click here if you want it in its own window](http://www.supernova.com/pub/Jordan/opteron.jpg) :)[alt text http://www.supernova.com/pub/Jordan/opteron.jpg](http://www.supernova.com/pub/Jordan/opteron.jpg)